# Division in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables created using queries:

```
create table person (SSN int, name varchar(50));
create table accountInfo (SSN int, accNo int, bank varchar(50));
insert into person values (123, "Alfred"), (467, "Bond"),(896, "Charly"), (563, "Debora");
insert into accountInfo values (123, 1111,"BoA");
insert into accountInfo values (467, 1222,"BoA");
insert into accountInfo values (123, 333,"Chase");
insert into accountInfo values (896, 444,"Chase");
insert into accountInfo values (123, 555,"USB");
insert into accountInfo values (467, 666,"USB");
```

My question is what would be the correct query to calculate `accountInfo` divided by `person`. I tried use this query but it doesn't quite work well.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT accountInfo.bank AS bank FROM accountInfo accountInfo1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT person.SSN FROM person
WHERE person.SSN NOT IN (SELECT accountInfo2.SSN FROM accountInfo accountInfo2 WHERE accountInfo2.bank = accountInfo1.bank));
```

The result should be

```
+------+
| SSN  |
+------+
| 123  |
+------+
```

Comment: what do you mean by this `what does table accountInfo divide by table person will produce` ?

Comment: Basically I want to find which SSN have an account under all the banks listed in the table.

Comment: do you have another table for `bank`?

Comment: No, there is only one table `accountInfo` that has bank in side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.SSN, COUNT(DISTINCT a.bank) AS bankCount
FROM person p 
JOIN accountInfo a ON a.SSN = p.SSN
GROUP BY p.SSN
HAVING bankCount = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bank) FROM accountInfo);
```